# How to select max count of individual names written in a column

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table with a column having student names:
one student name can be entered more than once.
So if we want to find out which students are in the table and how many times ...
how can we count that?

I'm using DB2.

Comment: The question title asks a harder (slightly harder) question than the body of the question asks.  You've got two correct answers for the simpler question asked in the body of the question; you don't yet have an answer to the harder question.  Please remember that tables have names; it is a nuisance to have to invent table names when answering questions. (`WITH name_count AS (SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS num FROM A_Table GROUP BY name) SELECT name, num FROM name_count WHERE num = (SELECT MAX(num) FROM name_count)` should provide the answer to the more complex question in the title.)

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, count(*) 
from   your_table
group by name;
```

or

```
select name, count(*)
from   your_table
where  name = 'xxx'
group by name;
```

Comment: The second seems rather pointless . I mean name='xxx' then grouping by name .

Comment: The GROUP BY is needed in DB2 and standard SQL if the name is selected in the select-list.  It would be possible just to have the COUNT(*) and then the GROUP BY would be unnecessary.

Comment: Now that I've had some sleep, I guess I was trying to demonstrate a where clause. An name `in ('xxx', 'yyy')` or in with a subquery would be a better example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, count(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name
```